# Пылесосить

Tags: грамотная-речь

Доброго времени суток всем.
Хотелось бы знать, как образовать форму первого лица единственного числа глагола **пылесосить**.

Comment: О том же: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424999/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d1%88%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8e/425000#425000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаю пылесосинг. ;)

Вопрос неочевиден.
Большинство более старых словарей (Кузнецов, например) считают "пылесосить" глаголом с неполной парадигмой, первое лицо в обоих числах отсутствует.
Современные словари (Лопатин) чаще дают форму "пылесошу", встречается и вариант с равноправными "пылесошу" и "пылесосю".

На всякий случай. Обобщать на некоторые "похожие" глаголы (куролесить, околесить и т.п.) не стоит. Там проблем обычно не возникает. Сложность "пылесосить" связана с формой "сосать, сосу", которую интуитивно хочется перенести на "пылесосить, *пылесосу".

Comment: Пылесосинг :)! До недавнего времени ребят приходилось предупреждать, что если в тесте будет вариант пылесошу - это неверный ответ. В учебниках и пособиях по культуре речи до сих пор предупреждают о том, что это ошибка. Но как же правильно - не встречала вариантов ни в одном пособии. Если вместо "победю" - можно сказать "одержу победу", "сумею победить", то в случае с пылесосом...(убираю пылесосом или с помощью пылесосоа для разговорной речи длинно!) Кодификаторам ничего не оставалось как все-таки зафиксировать "пылесошу" как правильный.

Comment: Я предполагал, что это "победю" может всплыть в данной теме. Но увы, это разные случаи. "Пылесошу" нормально образуется и сложность здесь скорее грамматическая. 

А победю/побежу - обе формы несвободны и конкурируют друг с другом. Какая из них могда бы претендовать на роль правильной, непонятно. 
аналогично бдить, ерундить, берендить... Довольно длинный ряд получается.

Answer (score 4):

*"Я пылесошу"* - единственная правильная форма. Происходит чередование "с" и "ш".

Comment: Плюс: [ссылка](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EF%FB%EB%E5%F1%EE%F1%E8%F2%FC&all=x).

Comment: Плюс - к чему? К привету Владимиру Владитмировичу?

Я же русским по белому написал:

>Современные словари (Лопатин) чаще дают форму "пылесошу", встречается и вариант с равноправными "пылесошу" и "пыоесосю".

Comment: Я ваше не читаю, пропускаю )

Comment: Как прикажите понимать? "Плюс к тому, что я ваше не читаю"?
Или "Пастернака не читала, но осуждаю". ©

Привет Владимир Владимирычу не забыли передать?

Comment: В дополнение хочу сказать, что "сосать, сосу" (упомянутое behemothus'ом) тут ни при чём, т.к. инфинитив от "пылесошу" -- это "пылесо́с**и**ть", а не "пылесос**á**ть".

Comment: При чём, поскольку слова похожие и форму одного *интуитивно хочется* перенести на другое.

Answer (score -2):

Пылесосить - слово-ублюдок из жаргона домохозяек.
Удивительно, почему они до сих пор не мясорубкают, не кофемолкают, не щёткают, не стаканят чай, не тряпкают стол и т.д. 
Правила русского языка позволяют легко и просто образовать из существительного глагол и наоборот. Например, плавать - плавание, стол - столоваться. Это нормально и привычно. Но можно и непривычно: стул - пристулиться.
Есть и сложносочинённые слова из существительного и глагола: возить паром - паровоз, марать бумагу - бумагомаратель, сосать пыль - пылесос.
Заметим, что НИ ОДНО из таких слов кроме пылесоса не произвело глагола. НЕТ и не нужны слова паровозить, бумогомарать, кофемолкать, мясорубкать , и пылесосить тоже НЕ НУЖНО. Паровоз возит, кофемолка мелет, мясорубка рубит, пылесос сосёт. Если вам не нравится сосать - ЧИСТИТЕ! Когда я попрошу дочь почистить ковёр или диван, мне всё равно, как она это сделает, да хоть языком вылижет. А если вдруг не всё равно, так я добавлю ОДНО слово - почисти пылесосом.
Предвижу возражение - нам так удобно. Да, в быту между собой вы как угодно общайтесь, никто вам не указ. Я лишь против легализации незаконорождённого слова.
На мой взгляд недопустимо ломать нормы русского языка ради мнимого удобства.
То, что псевдолингвисты до сих пор спорят, как правильно - пылесосю или пылесошу, только подтверждает моё мнение о ненормативности этого слова-ублюдка.
Другое возражение - одно слово короче двух.
У меня есть контрвозражение. Вы постоянно, почти непрерывно произносите десятки и сотни ненужных слов просто ради общения, вот там боритесь за краткость. А там, где важно, не жалко сказать два слова.
Если вы не согласны, приведите пример ДРУГОГО подобного глагола, образованного от существительного, образованного из существительного и глагола.
Мне будет интересно.
Наконец, не трудитесь меня хулить, то есть ставить так называемые "дизлайки".
А конструктивное обсуждение приветствуется.