# Спряжение в сленге

Tags: просторечия

Сленговые выражения иногда основаны на обычных, только смысл изменен. Вот, например, выражение "косить под <кого-то>". Как это сказать в первом лице? Если бы разговор был о косьбе травы, я бы сказала "я кошу траву".Но можно ли сказать "я кошу под психа"? Как-то не звучит. Так и хочется сказать "косю", ведь смысл-то другой!

Comment: "Косу" уж тогда. Как "сосу", "пасу" и проч.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не зависит от изменения значения. Здесь морфонологические изменения - позиционные чередования ещё в др.-р. языке: губные [б], [п], [м], [в] и переднеязычные [д], [т], [з], [с] были твердыми перед гласными непереднего ряда, полумягкими перед гласными переднего ряда и в сочетании с [j] изменяли свое качество: б + j → бл: любить – люблю,т + j → ч: свет – свеча , з + j → ж: отрезать – отрежу, с + j → ш: косить – кошу.

Поэтому КОСЮ в русском языке невозможно.

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему это закон продолжает действовать - и почему он действует столь избирательно. "Во всю (Ивановскую)" - можно, а куролесю, колесю, колбасю и ересю - нет?!

Comment: Так я же написала, что это МОРФОНОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ изменения, а не просто фонетические.Это происходит в русских глаголах, в их корнях (в других морфах другие процессы)

Comment: Я понимаю, что "косю " невозможно. Но есть какое-то внутреннее желание "расподобить" формы с разным смыслом. Но, видимо, это мое личное желание.

Comment: >Так я же написала, что это МОРФОНОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ изменения, а не просто фонетические.  
Это, увы, не объясняет избирательности действия древнего правила.
Да и тот факт, что закон продолжает действовать хоть в каком-то виде - тоже не объясняет до конца. Но вопросы "почему" я стараюсь обычно не задавать, если нет намерения услышать прямое объяснение причинно-следственной связи. Поэтому ограничимся хотя бы избирательностью. У нее-то должно быть какое-то объяснение...  Для каких конкретно морфов закон в силе? Я пока что не очень могу это сформулировать. При том, что сам Ваш ответ вполне справедлив.

Comment: В силе для корней глаголов, а почему - я не учёный, я учитель на пенсии, в такие глубины не лезу, если честно, для меня старославянский. историческая грамматика и в молодости были доступны лишь поверхностно. в общем, и даже желания лезть дальше не было.И так огромный материал нужно было уложить в голове. Вот сейчас есть время покопаться во всём, но вроде как уже и не нужно.Большее значение имеет общение. А на всех этих сайтах я для того, чтоб мозги не засохли.

Answer (score 1):

Изменяются одинаково: я кошу (что?)траву и кошу (под кого?) под дурака.

Answer (score 1):

В  соответствии  с  фонетическим   законом,  сложившимся  ещё  в  древнерусском  языке  сказать  косю  и  пылесосю  невозможно.  Но,  судя  по  высказываниям   участников  обсуждения  данного  вопроса,  невозможность  эта   далеко  не  абсолютная. Но может  и  закон  потихоньку   изменяется.

Comment: Есть маловразумительные словарные формы : месить/**мешу**, басить/**башу**. Вряд ли кто так говорит. Дерзить - "1 л. ед. не  употр." Не хватает иногда средств в языке выразить все возможные формы правильно. Остается нам говорить *по-простецки*, люди все равно поймут и *простят*.

Answer (score 0):

> Так и хочется сказать "косю"

Ну, не знаю. Мне сказать "косю" совсем не хочется:))Так же, как "пылесосю".

Answer (score 0):

Ну "пылесосю" маленько не в тему. "Пылесошу" тоже не скажете, как и "пылесосУ" (от "сосать пыль").

Добавляю:

[Здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5739/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) можно посмотреть. Но у меня вариант "пылесошу" не проиносится.

Comment: А как же говорить? Я говорю "пылесошу", почему так нельзя?

Comment: А  мне  и  пылесосю,  и  косю  не  претит !  В  смысле  "косю  под  психа".  А  "пылесосю"  даже  приятней.  Но - траву  кошу!  Как  всё  запущено,  однако.

Comment: "Пылесошу" потихонечку признается возможным вариантом. 
И сложность  здесь другого плана. Интуитивно хочется свести к форме "сосать-сосу", но "пылесосу" совершенно невозможно, т.к. требовало бы ударения на последний слог, что для подобных многосложных глаголов нехарактерно.

Comment: "Сосать" тут не проходит, потому что от словосочетания "сосать пыль" образован новый глагол "пылесосить", по морфемной и фонетческой структуре  близкий "косить", "просить". Поэтому и приживается в языке "пылесошу" (как "кошу", "прошу").

Comment: >"Сосать" тут не проходит,  
  
А куда ему проходить??? То, что не работает как образец для "пылесосить", это понятно, только причем здесь фонетическая - тем более морфемная(!) - близость к "косить" или "просить"? Да и есть ли она, эта близость?

Answer (score 0):

> Я понимаю, что "косю " невозможно. Но есть какое-то внутреннее желание "расподобить" формы с разным смыслом. Но, видимо, это мое личное желание.

Нет! Это не личное. Это - тенденция, закон языка как знаковой системы. Обозначать разные предметы одним словом (омонимия) и обозначать разными словами один предмет (синонимия) противно самой сути знаковой системы. Система требует однозначных взаимных (взаимно-однозначных :-)) соответствий между знаками и значениями; система стремится вытеснять все неоднозначности.

Ну, система не может, конечно, сама что-то делать (она же не живая), но мы можем улавливать её требования именно в виде вот таких наших "личных желаний".