# Как правильно: пылесошу или пылесосю?

Tags: орфография

Собственно вопрос вынесен в заголовок. Контекст такой:

- Я вчера пылесосил
- Я завтра буду пылесосить
- Я сегодня **пылесосю** или **пылесошу**

Как правильно?

Comment: О том же:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5739/%d0%9f%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Словари, первоначально включившие в себя сам глагол, отрицали возможность его употребления в первом лице. Позже у Ожегова оба варианта приводились как равноценные, но предлагалось избегать употребления того и другого. Если же глагол в первом лице утвердится, меньшим из зол будет вариант с -шу, поскольку с таким окончанием существуют другие глаголы (косить - кошу и т. п.).

[Пылесосю или пылесошу? | Наука и жизнь](https://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/23481/)

Comment: Типа как `победю-побежду`?

Comment: Не считаете ли вы нужным доработать ответ в связи с изменениями норм языка, зафиксированных в словарях? Вопрос популярный, и это будет кстати. *(Это не обязательно! Просто предложение.)*

Answer (score 5):

*Правильно*: использую пылесос. Слово "пылесосить" пока не фиксируется ни в одном подходящем словаре (орфоэпическом), поэтому для себя можете говорить, как вам вздумается. Я для себя решил, что "пылесошу" мне больше подходит. Причины - см. Alex_ander

Comment: использую пылесос - допускает многозначные толкования, например, `использую пылесос для продувки`, а термин `пылесошу` - однозначно трактуется как использование прибора по прямому назначению.

Comment: @Бармалей *допускает многозначные толкования* - ну мало ли какие слова есть многозначные. ))) Зато верно на все 100%. Пока отвечал, нашел у Зарвы "пылесошу". Это, во-первых, словарь профильный, во-вторых, консервативный. Так что вопрос, считайте, решен.

Comment: Не считаете ли вы нужным доработать ответ в связи с изменениями норм языка, зафиксированных в словарях? Вопрос популярный, и это будет кстати. *(Это не обязательно! Просто предложение.)*

Answer (score 4):

Все-таки считаю нужным привести выдержки:

1. "ПылесОсить, пылесОшу, пылесОсит" (Орфоэпический словарь русского языка Н. А. Еськовой (РАН). Москва: АСТ, 2015).
2. "ПылесОсить, -сОшу, -сОсишь" (Толковый словарь русского языка С. И. Ожегова; 28-е издание М.: Мир и Образование, 2016).
3. "ПылесОсить, -Ошу, -Осишь (разг.)" (Толковый словарь русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов РАН (Н. Ю. Шведова). М., 2011: Издательский центр "Азбуковник").
4. "ПылесОсить, -Ошу, -Осит" (Русский орфографический словарь РАН. М.: АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2015).
5. "ПылесОсить, -сОшу, -сОсит, -сОсят" (Словарь правильной русской речи (ИЛИ РАН). М.: АСТ: Астрель, 2008).